# I/O C++ Reading from a text file

Tags: c++, io

In my program I'm inputting a file and inside the file is something like this:

> 11267    2   500.00      2.00

...that is one line. There are more lines set up in that same order. I need to input the first number, `11267`, into `actnum`. After that, `2` into `choice`, etc. I simply lack the logic to figure out how to input just the first 5 numbers into the first variable.

```
actnum = 11267;
choice = 2;
```

Edit*

I have all of that:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;



void main()
{
    int trans = 0, account;
    float ammount, bal;

    cout << "ATM" << endl;
```

etc etc

I just dont know how to get it to only input the specific numbers into it. Like when I do the >>actnum >> choice how does it know to put just the first 5 numbers in it?

Answer (score 2):

Use the C++ `<fstream>` library. `fscanf()` is slightly out of date and you will probably get better performance from `<fstream>`, not to mention that the code is a lot easier to read:

```
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

ifstream fileInput("C:\foo.txt");
fileInput >> actnum >> choice >> float1 >> float2;
```

Comment: +1 Quick, remove the "*and you will probably get better performance from `<fstream>`*" before some micro-optimization is evil dude comes along and downvotes you for no reason.

Comment: @muntoo lol if it runs faster, they should be happy :) Also, even if it doesn't run faster, readability is a significant bonus (especially with C++)

Comment: I have all of that:

    #include <fstream>
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    
    
    
    void main()
    {
     int trans = 0, account;
     float ammount, bal;
    
     cout << "ATM" << endl;


etc etc

I just dont know how to get it to only input the specific numbers into it. Like when I do the >>actnum >> choice how does it know to put just the first 5 numbers in it?

Comment: @Brisil the `iostream`, `fstream`, and similar i/o libraries are space delimited. this means that when they input a space, they will stop and save the rest of the input for the next call. so when you put `fileInput >> actnum >>...` it will stop at the space in the file and input the next number into the variable put in the next call (`...>> choice >> float1...`)

Answer (score 1):

fscanf is what you are looking for. it works the same as scanf, but is for files.

```
unsigned int actnum, choice;
float float1, float2;

FILE *pInputFile = fopen("input.txt", "r");

fscanf(pInputFile, "%u %u %f %f", &actnum, &choice, &float1, &float2);
```

Comment: While this is using C stdio library rather than C++'s fstream, I find the concise format string more readable. Especially with more complicated formats.

Comment: don't forget to `#include <stdio.h>` at the beginning of the program, or this will not compile

Comment: If you're gonna go this way, better `#include <cstdio>` instead. It should play nicer with C++

Answer (score 1):

```
input_file_stream >> actnum >> choice >> ...
```

Comment: +1 for the C++ way to do it. Just one suggestion: Make it clear that `input_file_stream` is an `std::ifstream`, and point the OP to the documentation

Comment: I have all of that:

    #include <fstream>
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    
    
    
    void main()
    {
     int trans = 0, account;
     float ammount, bal;
    
     cout << "ATM" << endl;


etc etc

I just dont know how to get it to only input the specific numbers into it. Like when I do the >>actnum >> choice how does it know to put just the first 5 numbers in it?

Comment: Those are 5 digits, but a single number. When you extract an integer, it reads while it can interpret an integer, and the space marks the end of it.